# How to run function on every object REST call returns or active one?

Tags: 2013, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Missing one important component here. I'm making a REST call with jQuery ajax, and would like to know how to run my if statement for all items or the current active item [this] instead of just the first value in the array that returns to me.  See code below:

```
$.ajax({
   url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('My List')/items?$select=Field",
   type: "GET",
   headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose"},
   success: function (data){
       $.each(data, function(){
          var field = data.d.results;
     if (**field[0]**.DocLink.Description.length > 0){
    console.log(Works);
    }
     else alert("proof")'
    });
    },
});
```

**Code works if I use bracket notation to select first object in array, comes back undefined without it.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the proper syntax of the [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function.

`$.each()` expects two parameters: the first is the array that you're looping through, and the second is a callback function to execute for every element of the array.

So when you have an array stored in the variable `data.d.results`, you can loop through each of the items in the array by doing something like this:

```
$.each(data.d.results, function(index,item){ 
    //do something with the item value here
    console.log(item);
});
```